# Best way to show two fields of one related object in ModelAdmin

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms, django-admin

I have this model:

```
class ProductType(models.Model):
    project = models.ForeignKey(Proekt)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
```

I use ForeignKey for this model in another model and I need to know what's the best way to show both fields of this object. Let's say, One of them should be select and another - just readonly text field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's unclear what you're asking. Do you need something different from the default Django model admin as documented here:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects

Edit:

In that case, you'll want to modify the form used in the modeladmin, probably the easiest way to do this is with `modeladmin.get_form()` and then `formfield_overrides` to change the widget.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.formfield_overrides

Comment: Yes I do. When I select the ProductType in Dropdown list I need to show it's name in other form field that should be readonly and shouldn't be stored in db.